# How to determine for which value of an unknown parameter, one eigenvalue is 0?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrix: 
 
$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
a & 1 & 0 \\
4 & a & 1 \\
0 & 0 & a \end{bmatrix}$ 
 
for which value of the parameter $a$ one eigenvalue is certainly equal to $0$? 
 
The fact is that my professor asked to answer without the use of the **characteristic polynomial**.

Comment: The matrix has a zero eigenvalue if and only if the matrix is singular (if and only if determinant zero), so at least one value for $a$ that works is obvious.  There is a less obvious solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the eigenvalues being $0$ means the matrix is singular. Look at the first two columns of your matrix and try to figure out which value of $a$ makes these two columns linearly dependent.

Alternatively, you can make use of the fact your matrix has a block structure. The eigenvalues of your matrix are the union of the eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix}a & 1 \\ 4 &a\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}a\end{bmatrix}$. $a = 0$ immediately gives an eigenvalue at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

I see two ways of solving this without explicitly using the characteristic polynomial:

1. An eigenvalue of a matrix is $0$ if and only if the determinant of the matrix is zero. The determinant of $A$ is (expanding over the last row first) equal to $$a\begin{vmatrix}a&1\\4&a\end{vmatrix} = a(a^2-4).$$ Setting this to $0$ gives you three possible solutions for $a$. The problem with this solution is that it implicitly still uses the characteristic polynomial, as it gives the same equations as you would get if you fist took the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)$ and then set $p(0)=0$.
2. $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if $A$ is not invertible. For example, taking $a=0$ clearly makes $A$ non-invertible, so $0$ is its eigenvalue. Taking $a\neq 0$, you know that you can perform manipulations on $A$ which preserve rank, so you subtract $\frac{a}{4}\cdot$(second row) from the first and flip their order to get $$\begin{bmatrix}4&a&1\\0 & 1-\frac{a^2}4 & \frac a4\\0&0&a\end{bmatrix}.$$ This upper triangular matrix is invertible if all its diagonal entries are nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Try $a=2$. What can you say about the rows (or columns) of the matrix?

Comment: This "hint" looks like guessing.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I always guess my answers before trying a more deductive approach. There's nothing wrong about guessing, and I think it's no use to give the full answer right now. Besides, hardmath's comment already gave more away even.

Comment: I honestly think that " **always** guessing my answers before..." is a rather wrong method to do mathematics. in particular in cases as the present one where there can be infinite different "guessings" and yours doesn't seem to be  better a priori than any other one.

Comment: "Always" was probably putting it too strongly. But I think it's important to guess. Besides, I am under the impression that because of the way I formulated the hint, you think that I first guessed the answer and then motivated my guess. Nothing is farther from the truth, I already had a certain approach in mind before making the guess.

Comment: Then I think it is important to hint at the way the value $\;2\;$ was obtained and not as the value itself, just as hardmath explains it, and not merely to hint to try $\;2\;$ like out of the blue.

Comment: I didn't mean to generate a methodological argument. I find the hint absolutely helpful to justify and address my view towards the heart of the problem, but, at the same time, I couldn't have managed to understand the usefulness of it without the missing theoretical basis of the solution. Thank you nonetheless.